# Adjusting parskip only between regular text paragraphs

Tags: itemize, parskip

If I use the package `parskip` with something like `\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}` it adjusts `parskip` **not only** between text paragraphs, but **also** between text and e.g. `itemize` environments.

In the example below, I only want to change the space between e.g. Paragraph 1 and Paragraph 2, but **not** between **paragraphs** an **itemize environments** (e.g. Paragraph 3 and the items below)

```
Paragraph 1 ...

Paragraph 2 ...

Paragraph 3 ...
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
```

What's a good way to make this change for the full document?

---

### MWE of the above

Here's an MWE for testing purposes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep,nolistsep}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

Paragraph 3 ...
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable?

Comment: @leandriis Thanks - I just did (I added an MWE for it)

Comment: Use `topsep` option as `\begin{itemize}[topsep=-5mm]`. The `topsep` value is equal to your `\parskip` value as negative.

Comment: As you have discovered there are many occasions in LaTeX where a paragraph is used where you do not expect it.